# How do I find the intervals in which I have to calculate the integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

I have to calculate the $\int_{E}1\,dx\,dy$ of the following set $C=\bigl\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}:1\leq x^2y \leq8, x\leq y\ \leq 27x\bigr\}$. I have to know in which interval I take  $x$ and in which I take $y$.
I have so many exercises like this, that I have to understand which the boundaries are from a given set, and I am struggling a lot. Sometimes at least one of them is clearer and I set the other as a function of the first one. Please If somebody could explain to me how I can generally do it, any sort of tip.

I have an end exam coming up and I have no idea what I'll do with this sort of exercise.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're struggling with here. If you wrote the inequalities as $$ \frac 1 {x^2} \leq y \leq \frac{8}{x^2} \quad, \quad   x\leq y \leq 27x$$ would that help ? Or is it still unclear what you should do ?

Comment: Use the equations to find their intersection points and do a rough sketch with at least some values to get an idea of what limits to use for the integral. In this case, you will have to break your integral in $3$ unless you do a change of variable. Are you aware with change of variable?

Answer (score 1):

We can rewrite the inequalities defining $C$ as

$$ \frac 1 {x^2} \leq y \leq \frac{8}{x^2} \quad, \quad   x\leq y \leq 27x$$

Which is the same as

$$ \max\left(\frac{1}{x^2},x \right)\leq y \leq \min\left(\frac{8}{x^2}, 27x\right)$$

Since

$$ \max\left(\frac{1}{x^2},x \right) =
 \begin{cases} 1/x^2 & x \leq 1 \\ x 
 & x \geq 1 \end{cases}$$

and
$$ \min\left(\frac{8}{x^2},27x \right) =
 \begin{cases} 27 x & x \leq 2/3 \\ 8/x^2 
 & x \geq 2/3 \end{cases}$$

We will split the integral in three parts with

- $ 1/x^2 \leq y \leq 27x$  and $x \leq 2/3.$
- $ 1/x^2 \leq y \leq 8/x^2$ and $x \in [2/3,1]$.
- $ x \leq y \leq 8/x^2$ and $x \geq 1$

Clearly these conditions are the same as

- $  1/x^2 \leq y \leq 27x$  and $1/3 \leq x \leq 2/3.$
- $ 1/x^2 \leq y \leq 8/x^2$ and $x \in [2/3,1]$.
- $ x \leq y \leq 8/x^2$ and $1 \leq x \leq 2$

Of course you could've found this just by making a sketch like the one Bernard provided.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an image of the domain of integration, if it may help:

[image]